How to implement rectangular highlight tool on ember
I want to implement a rectangular highlight tool as seen on google.com -> Settings -> Send Feedback -> Capture Screenshot -> Highlight or Hide info.
Seems very complicated and I'm not sure where to start. How would you do it with Ember?

You'd probably first want to capture the screen as an image,
maybe with

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image

and then allow editing of that image

draw the image to a canvas

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage


use mouse events to draw the rectangle

see here: Let users draw rectangles with mouse in canvas with Javascript



then save the canvas content to an image

How To Save Canvas As An Image With canvas.toDataURL()?

